# ssh tunnel not working with terminal

Tags: mac-osx, ssh-tunnel

I must set up a ssh tunnel on a Mac OS X, to access to some servers.

So I did on the Mac OS :

1. ssh -D 9999 user@host
2. In the preference system, I had a proxy SOCKS (localhost:9999)
3. In the /etc/hosts I had the ips for the servers
4. the Mac Os can now access to the servers with it browser, for example.

But, with a terminal, it can't reach the servers. 
I Guess it's because the terminal do not use the "preference system".

So what does I have to do to get this tunnel working with the terminal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the specific command-line program you're using.  For example, `curl` has a bunch of options for using different versions of the socks proxy protocol:

```
curl -s --socks5 localhost:9999 http://myip.is/ | grep javascript:doCopy
```

(this should show the public IP of the computer you ssh'ed into.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have a typo - looks like you have three 9's in your ssh command and four 9's in your socks

What program are you using from the terminal, this program would most likely have to be configured to use the local proxy.

Comment: it's a typo error.

Well, all the program, for example **curl** doesn't reach the servers

Comment: Are you using the socks5 flag?

--socks5 <host[:port]>

Use the specified SOCKS5 proxy - but resolve the host name locally. If the port number is not specified, it is assumed at port 1080.

This option overrides any previous use of -x, --proxy, as they are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Only few programs can use SOCKS Proxies natively. Some programs can be forced through the Proxy, though, with tools like tsocks.

Nice alternative: Create tunnels listening on 127.0.0.X, X starting at 2 and being increased for every server, and edit hosts accordingly.

```
ssh -L127.0.0.2:80:server:80 user@proxy
```